# UIImageView Animation Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c

Just started Objective-C - trying to make 4 images fadein/fadeout continuously.

The code below is not working. I know the button is working because the text of my label changes, however no pictures animate. No errors either ...

h.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{

    IBOutlet UIImageView *viewer;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *viewer;

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;

@end
```

m.

```
-(IBAction)startImageViewAnimation
{

label1.text = @"CHECK?";

NSArray *animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"backgrounds_app1-01.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"backgrounds_app2-02.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"backgrounds_app3-03.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"backgrounds_app4-04.png"],
                            nil];

viewer = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
viewer.animationImages = animationImages ;
viewer.animationRepeatCount = 2;
viewer.animationDuration= 4.0;
[viewer startAnimating];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self
                               selector:@selector(animationDone:)
                               userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


}

-(void)animationDone:(NSTimer*)inTimer
{
[inTimer invalidate];
inTimer = nil;
NSLog(@"animationDone ");
}
```

Comment: change the alloc line to: `viewer = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]`

Comment: @rounak did it - still nothing.

Comment: Does it matter that I set the image of the UIImageView? Or does it have to be blank?

Answer (score 2):

After initialising the image view, you'll have to add it as a subview:

```
viewer = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:viewer];
```

Comment: Perfect! - 2 questions: a) what does that do? is it applicable to other situations?

Comment: b) can the animation be smoother?

Comment: a: yes, without adding the subview to the view it exists, but will not show up. This counts for any view.

Comment: b:if you want to create a fade-in/out animation, consider using [UIView animateWithDuration] and change the alpha value of the image accordingly

Comment: Doubt the alpha of the image itself can be changed. You'll need to have at least two UIImageViews and change the alpha of that view.

Comment: @rounak why do you doubt it?

Comment: @RobP because `UIImage` doesn't have an `alpha` property on it?

Comment: umm, right, good point ;) the hosting view, as you say, then.